# How do I import ruby gems assets to project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems

I  develop gem named gemini.

like this: in gemini assets file gemini.coffee required bootstrap plugins and gemini.scss import bootstrap.scss.

Anothor project named: study, the assets appplication.js require gemini.coffee and application.css import gemini.scss

Study project Gemfile config gemini then bundle 
Start study project services and open http://localhost:3000 but raise error: **File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets.**

I want to know:

1. how do i require gemini.scss to my project and also it required bootstrap plugins
2. why raise error
3. what is best practice develop ruby gems

thks for everyone!

Comment: i just found answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115588/wrapping-the-bootstrap-sass-gem-in-another-gem-causes-asset-manifests-to-break